# HTML5 pattern that will accept alphanumerical without spaces

Tags: regex

I know that it's a basic code but would you mind.

here's a pattern i did that can accept lower/uppercase characters and numbers.

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{1,25}
```

How could i add to the pattern that will not accept spaces?

Comment: It already doesn't match spaces. You might have to use the correct function for matching though, e.g. match() instead of find(), or surround the Regex with `^$`, i.e. `^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,25}$`.

Comment: @Njol: HTML5 input `pattern` attribute is automatically anchored

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[A-Za-z0-9\S]{1,25}
```

This should do. As `\S` matches all non whitespace characters

Comment: Since range `A-Za-z0-9` are indeed non whitespace, simple `\S{1,25}` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You must add anchors to be sure that your pattern describes the string from start to end:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,25}$
```

`^` start of the string

`$` end of the string

Otherwise your pattern will match any string that contains at least one alnum like: `#!$ a ))[`